# "CoreFoundation.h: Not found" when building for iOS device, but OK for Simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, core-foundation

When building for "Device", I get the following error:

```
CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h: No such file or directory
```

It is building fine for the **Simulator**.

I searched but didn't get working solution

I am using **Xcode 4.3.2**.

Comment: We mark questions as duplicate whenever we perceive it is indeed a duplicate - even if you ask us not to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Project "Build Settings" .

Search for framework search paths, and then remove any path that is visible in its content

Comment: deleted but hard luck,not working.What is the reason i think i have added the right framework then why so?